# I need to get the same results without starmap

Tags: python, function, lambda

I'm not allowed to use functions or lambda, but I have to get the same results as if I was using them.

```
from itertools import starmap

#the max p you can have for your square pair.
max_P = number
square_pairs = sorted(
((x_square-y_square) // 2, P, x_square, y_square)
for parity in (1, 2)
for x in range(parity, int((2*max_P)**.5)+1, 2)
for y in range(parity, x, 2)
if (P := ((x_square:=x**2)+(y_square:=y**2)) // 2) <= max_P
)
print(
'N\tP\tN+P\tP-N\n---------------------------',
'\n'.join(starmap('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}'.format, square_pairs)),
sep='\n'
)
```

I need the same output this gives without using starmap.

Comment: Python docs include rough equivalent of [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) that you can use in the code directly.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python docs include rough equivalent of `starmap` definition, you can just paste that into your code directly and reuse it that way to circumvent weird requirements like "no imports".

```
def starmap(function, iterable):
    # starmap(pow, [(2,5), (3,2), (10,3)]) --> 32 9 1000
    for args in iterable:
        yield function(*args)
        
print(
    'N\tP\tN+P\tP-N\n---------------------------',
    '\n'.join(starmap('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}'.format, square_pairs)),
    sep='\n'
)
```

"I'm not allowed to use functions" - that's stupid requirement. You can't write code without functions.

Answer (score 0):

Since `starmap()` simply calls the function for each element of an iterable object, you could also replace it with a list comprehension:

```py
'\n'.join(starmap('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}'.format, square_pairs)),
# is roughly equivalent to
'\n'.join(['{}\t{}\t{}\t{}'.format(*e) for e in square_pairs])
# or
'\n'.join('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}'.format(*e) for e in square_pairs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print('N\tP\tN+P\tP-N')
print('---------------------------')
for p in square_pairs:
    print(*p, sep='\t')
```